# project.assets.json missing please run a nuget restore visual studio 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to run microsoft's example repository https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs

I successfully cloned the project. I am having trouble running it out of the box. Specifically, I am trying to run the Localization example project by running program.cs inside it. I cloned the whole repository and used visual studio to "Open Folder" and selected the Localization folder. I get a build error it says project.assets.json is missing please run a nuget restore when I try to run program.cs (in the localization example project). I can't do that because the nuget package manager is missing (I have access to the package manager console though) and I don't have a solution file to pass as a parameter to dotnet restore  from the console. What should I do to fix it?

Here is the specific part of the repository i am trying to run https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> project.assets.json missing please run a nuget restore visual studio
> 2019

When you download the [microsoft's example repository](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs), Unzip the file.

**1)** Open VS2019 IDE, use `Open a project or Solution` menu to open such file `xxx\aspnetcore\fundamentals\localization\sample\3.x\Localization\Localization.csproj` directly.

**Actually**, opening `xxx.csproj` or `xxx.sln` can show all the contents of the item in the Solution Explorer in its entirety.

**2)** build the project directly or just right-click on the solution-->**Restore NuGet Packages**.

[image]

**Then** you will build the **Localization** project successfully.

[image]